# What does "A realization of independent copies"?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, independence

I read in statistic, "a realization of independent copies" from "Elements of copula modelling with R", and do not understand the meaning. I search and found that it means, the two random variables have the same distribution, but they are independent [the source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957534/terminology-independent-copy-of-random-variables). I also found that the copies themself cannot be independent. That is, they are identical but not independent.

So, I still do not understand what does "a realization of independent copies" and why they are not independent?

Comment: can you post source of where you saw this quote?

Comment: "Elements of copula modelling with R"

Comment: @doubled Thank you for your comment. I add two sources.

Comment: The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352803/sample-space-for-mixture-of-two-normal-distributions/352897#352897 answers your question.