# A question regarding the proof of Schur product theorem

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, covariance-matrix, mathematical-statistics

I have a problem proving the following statement: if $A$ and $B$ are positive definite $n\times n$ matrices, then there exist independent random vectors $X$, $Y$ such that $X\sim N(0,A)$ and $Y\sim N(0,B)$. I know that if $A$ is positive definite, then for any $m$ there exist a random vector $X$ such that $X\sim N(m,S)$, but how to make $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Construct a joint distribution with a block-diagonal covariance matrix, the blocks being $A$ and $B$.   For the Normal distribution, this suffices to make $X$ and $Y$ independent, since the covariance between them will be zero and (for the Normal) this implies independence.

Comment: This is not a special property of Normal variables: there is a generic procedure, described in detail in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352897/919, for constructing independent random variables out of given distributions.