# Changing a conditional probability to a deterministic function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, conditional-probability, density-function, parameterization

Suppose that we have a conditional density function $p(y|x;\theta^*)$, where $\theta^*$ represents distribution parameters and are assumed to be deterministic. Is it possible that we write this conditional density as a deterministic function of $x$ and $\theta$ where $\theta$ is a random variable independent of $x$? In other words,

$y|x \sim p(y|x;\theta^*)$

is equivalent to

$y = g(x, \theta)$

$\theta \sim p(\theta)$

Furthermore, is this representation unique?

For example, if $y$ has a Gaussian distribution with mean $x$ and s.d. $\sigma^*$, we can write

$y = x + \sigma,$

where $\sigma$ has a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and s.d. $\sigma^*$. My question might be related to the question discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185751/how-to-find-the-deterministic-function-representation-of-a-random-variable).

Comment: It is hard to call your $p$ as conditional pdf, because there is no additional random component ($x$ and $\theta^*$ are fixed parameters).

Comment: " σ has a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and s.d. σ" -- please don't use the same symbol for two *completely* different things.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the s.d. to $\sigma^*$.

Comment: It would have been much better to stick with statistical convention and leave the s.d. as $\sigma$ and change the variable to a more conventional symbol in such a context (like $\varepsilon$ or $\eta$ or $\zeta$ or $\xi$), so that you had something like "For example, if $y$ has a Gaussian distribution with mean $x$ and s.d. $σ$, we can write

$y=x+\varepsilon$,
where $\varepsilon$
has a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and s.d. $σ$".